# Word for brands that mass produce cheap goods too?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't remember where I read this term/word. It's a name given to those brands that also produce goods that are cheap along with expensive ones, therefore still allowing people to hold on to the 'brand name'. Does anyone know this?

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium_pricing) *A premium pricing strategy involves setting the price of a product higher than similar products. This strategy is sometimes also called **skim pricing** because it is an attempt to “skim the cream” off the top of the market.*

Comment: Are you referring to the brand or the strategy? An example would help.

Comment: Why would they not be able to hold onto the brand name if they only produced expensive products? As far as I know, Rolex only produces watches that are several thousands of dollars in price, and they are at no risk of a failure of brand recognition.

Comment: @JasonBassford Because they (I) couldn't otherwise afford to have/wear the more expensive branded article at the *premium* price. I'd want the cheaper "second" with the brand prestige still attached in the form of the label.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm pretty sure it was a name given to the brand. For example, if Gucci made 100$ jeans (as opposed to their popular 10000$ jeans) they're brand would be called a ---- brand. I'm really sorry, this is all I can remember! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @laksheya I don't have a suggestion for the term; just clarifying: the word you're seeking will have the company mainly producing two sets of items, one cheap, one expensive, but the cheap ones aren't just reduced-price variants of the expensive ones, right? Like expensive shirts and suits but cheap jeans, as opposed to jeans that are sometimes expensive and sometimes cheap.

Comment: @Lawrence Sorry, I didn't really understand your query. When I was searching for this word I came across the term 'diffusion lines'. The word I'm looking for is a term for brands that make diffusion lines.

Comment: Could it be "Brand Extension" - "A common method of launching a new product by using an existing brand name on a new product in a different category."

Comment: One would think that if such a word existed it would be used in an article such as this: https://www.grailed.com/drycleanonly/fashion-diffusion-label-decline  but I didn't see one.

Comment: @Jim I really have no idea. I remember reading a wikipedia article about the term and everything. I'm sorry that I can't provide any more information! :(

Comment: @Stan I'm afraid your comment doesn't seem to address mine in any way. Again, why should Rolex make $30 watches? Their exorbitant prices don't seem to be hurting them in any way.

Comment: @laksheya There are *second-tier brands*, but those make only more affordable merchandise. There are also *luxury brands*, but those make high-end products—and may or may not have a diffusion line as well. I can't think of a phrase that means a company necessarily provides goods at both ends of the spectrum.

Answer (score -1):

According to [MoneyCrashers](https://www.moneycrashers.com/discount-designer-clothes-cheap/)…

> • **Capsule Collections**. Capsule collections are made up of a few staple pieces that best showcase a designer’s work or a certain brand collaboration. Because there are only a few staple pieces, the brand can mass manufacture the same jackets, pants, dresses, and skirts over and over again, driving down prices so they’re more affordable. You’ll still get the name and similar quality, but you’ll spend less. Capsule collections are also typically a limited run – once they’re gone, they’re gone.